# why does my url not update after migration?

Tags: permalinks, migration

program using: ubuntu 18.04

Problem: so i have two local wordpress sites running on my localhost, say site1.com and site2.com

I have migrated all of the databases from site1.com to site2.com. Now when I click on one of the link that's in site2.com, it's changing the URl to site1.com/pageIwantTovisit. I don't want that. I want it so that, if I'm on site2.com, then all the links should refer to site2.com/pageIwantToVisit.

I'm using phpmyadmin. I've changed the home and siteURL to site2.com but the links don't change unless i manually hardcode all the link which will take forever.

The link in site2.com should go from about page to blog page. 
Thank you.

Comment: Use [this script](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) to replace ALL urls in your database.

Comment: hey, I'm already using search and replace plugin from wordpress.

Comment: Clear browser cache

Answer (score 1):

When editing content in the content editor WordPress hardcodes the current URL that is being used to access the WordPress admin. This is usually found in link `href` and image `src`. There are several plugins or tools (like `wp-cli`) that can assist you in finding and replacing the url between environments.

You will likely want to your search to look something like:

Old
`//site1.com`

New
`//site2.com`

NO TRAILING SLASH in the search! Don't use the protocol if you are not trying to switch/normalize urls from `http` to `https`, same goes for `www` domain variants.

If you access the site at several different domains during the development cycle you may want to look into tools like the WordPress plugin `WP Migrate DB Pro` that find and replace while migrating between environments or manually on the current environment.